# When do i need to get permalink structure of a specific post?

Tags: permalinks

As already known that the function `the_permalink` echos out the URL for current post in the loop, while the function `get_permalink` returns the permalink for a specific post using `$post_id`, but `get_permalink` has the `$leavename` that allows return the URL structure of a post to finally (for example) get a URL that looks like this `http://localhost/%postname%/`. So, When do i may need such output?

Please notice the output:

```
   <?php 
        $x= get_permalink($post_id, true);
        echo $x;
        //output
        //http://localhost/%postname%/
    ?>
```

If i turned the `$leavename` to `false` i will already have the post name in the URL. So again , What makes  me turn it to `true`

Comment: I haven't seen anyone use that argument to get the permalink until now. It's mainly used simply as `get_permalink()`. It's an optional value to decide whether to keep the post's name or not.

Comment: but it doesn't output the post name, It outputs the `Structure Tag` for the post's name.

Comment: According to [WordPress developers](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/), it will decide to keep the name or not. Expand the code and notice the line 126 and 130. The `$leavevalue` is equal to `%postname%`

Comment: I have made an update, please notice the result of the added code, and tell me how to make use of such output?

Comment: I don't think that you would need to use `true` unless for developing purposes. As @Milo mentioned, the URL preview mechanism (or some plugins) use that function to update the slug based on the original post's name. You don't need it for theme development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used in admin context to display URL previews. When you change the slug of a post, the code that enables that mechanism is getting the format of the URL via that function.

Comment: Would you please consider the update made to the question

Comment: When you edit a post, there is a field that lets you change the slug, it uses Javascript to accomplish this. It gets the structure of the URL independent of the actual URL, so it can provide an interface for changing the URL. Consider that WP's internal code uses its own API, *you* will likely never use many if the API's features, simply because its use is specific to internal needs and not general themes or plugins.